# Android: How to catch 2 times short volume-up button push or long hold?

Tags: android, button, background-process, volume

I would like to run predefined service in my app if I do two short volume up pushes (or one long hold).

It should works also if phone has locked screen or another app is in foreground.

Thanks for any advice or example how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

The official Broadcast Receiver for volume changes only gets triggered when the state changes from volume to/from silent to/from vibrate. So perhaps, it could detect a long volume up hold under some circumstances, but I don't know. That Broadcast Receiver is not granular at all.

I've seen non-rooted apps on Google Play that detect the volume keys at a more granular level, but I believe those apps are making use of undocumented functionality (of which I do not know about).

If you're making your own rom as your username might imply, detecting those keys would be much easier to do. Is that the case? Are you making your own rom? Will the app you're making have root access?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, i don't creating my own rom. I just need to find solution, how to catch some hardware buttons on device.